# Last value of a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to use the following function;

`=INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D),1)`,

in order to get the last currency value of a column, but it returns #ERROR!.

[The value im trying to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPIiv.png)

As I montly update this spreadsheet, it would make it very convenient if would etract the last value in the column, e.g. the value marked in the image.

Is there a way (in Google Sheets) to find the last non-empty cell in this column, such that when I update the spreadsheet with a new "last value" it would return that value?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index(counta())` pattern will fail when the data is sparse, i.e., when there are blank values in the column.

The `index(match())` pattern will fail when the data contains a value that is not a number.

To find the last non-blank value in column `D`, regardless of data type, use the `+sort(row())` pattern:

`=+sort(D1:D; not(isblank(D1:D)) * row(D1:D); false)`

The formula uses semicolons as argument separators to make it work in any locale.

Answer (score 1):

If the column has only currency (ie number) values then you can use something like:

`=INDEX(D1:D, MATCH(999^99, D1:D))`

Answer (score 1):

or try:

```
=SORTN(D:D; 1;;ROW(D:D)*(D:D<>""); )
```